# C: Strings popped from stack are printed as trashvalues

Tags: c

I'm trying to separate elements of an equations (i.e. series of digits, series of letters and operators) into tokens to be stored in a stack for further use in a shunting-yard algorithm.

To that end I tried to identify the element at the start of the input string and then keeps going until it reaches a likely end. Once that is done, the examined bit of string is cut of the input and pushed on the stack. This part of the algorithm works fine until I push it. For some reason, when I pop every element of my stack and print them, they are displayed as random text often accompanied by '�' characters and I have no idea why.

I have used a stack implementation for C I found [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Stack#C). Both implementations didn't work and gave the same problem but the code below is written with the first one (the macro).

I have tested the code with the input `321 AZERTY`. Normally, at the last line, it should display

```
AZERTY
321
```

However, it displays

```
P�Hd�U
!^d�U
```

Or at least, that's what was displayed at the last execution. The exact content appears random but I don't think it has gone over 6 characters.

```c
#define DECL_STACK_TYPE(type, name) \
typedef struct stk_##name##_t{type *buf; size_t alloc,len;}*stk_##name; \
stk_##name stk_##name##_create(size_t init_size) {          \
    stk_##name s; if (!init_size) init_size = 4;            \
    s = malloc(sizeof(struct stk_##name##_t));          \
    if (!s) return 0;                       \
    s->buf = malloc(sizeof(type) * init_size);          \
    if (!s->buf) { free(s); return 0; }             \
    s->len = 0, s->alloc = init_size;               \
    return s; }                         \
int stk_##name##_push(stk_##name s, type item) {            \
    type *tmp;                          \
    if (s->len >= s->alloc) {                   \
        tmp = realloc(s->buf, s->alloc*2*sizeof(type));     \
        if (!tmp) return -1; s->buf = tmp;          \
        s->alloc *= 2; }                    \
    s->buf[s->len++] = item;                    \
    return s->len; }                        \
type stk_##name##_pop(stk_##name s) {                   \
    type tmp;                           \
    if (!s->len) abort();                       \
    tmp = s->buf[--s->len];                     \
    if (s->len * 2 <= s->alloc && s->alloc >= 8) {          \
        s->alloc /= 2;                      \
        s->buf = realloc(s->buf, s->alloc * sizeof(type));} \
    return tmp; }                           \
void stk_##name##_delete(stk_##name s) {                \
    free(s->buf); free(s); }                    \
type stk_##name##_get(stk_##name s) {         \
  type tmp;                                  \
    if (!s->len) abort();                       \
  tmp = s->buf[1];                     \
  return tmp;                                 \
}


#define stk_empty(s) (!(s)->len)
#define stk_size(s) ((s)->len)

DECL_STACK_TYPE(char *, str)

void str_to_stk(char* input, stk_str output) {
  while (input[0] != '\0') {
    if (isdigit((input[0]))) {
      int i = 0; 
      char* buffer = (char*) calloc(strlen(input)*sizeof(char),0);
      while ((isdigit(input[i]) || input[i] == '.') && input[i] != '\0') {
        strncat(buffer, &input[i], 1);
        i++;
      }
      stk_str_push(output, buffer);
      input = input+i;
      free(buffer);
    }
    else if (isalpha(input[0])) {
      int i = 0; char* buffer = (char*) calloc(strlen(input)*sizeof(char),0);
      while (isalpha(input[i]) && input[i] != '\0') {
        strncat(buffer, &input[i], 1);
        i++;
      }
      stk_str_push(output, buffer);
      input = input+i;
      free(buffer);
    }
    else if (isoperator(input[0]) || input[0] == '(' || input[0] == ')') {
      char buffer[2]; buffer[0] = input[0]; buffer[1] = '\0';
      stk_str_push(output, buffer);
      input = input+1;
    }
    else {
      input++;
    }
  }
  while (!stk_empty(output)) printf("%s\n", stk_str_pop(output));
}

void main() {
  char *input = "321 AZERTY";
  stk_str output = stk_str_create(20);

  str_to_stk(input, output);
}
```

Although I'm not necessarily new to programming, I have mostly worked on Java (a while back) and especially MATLAB with a (little) bit of Python (numpy mostly) on the side. When it comes to C however, I'm still a newcomer and I'm trying to learn it both for future university project and maybe future contributions to open-source projects.

Comment: What is `stk_str_push`? What is `DECL_STACK_TYPE`? Please show a [mcve]. The problem is most likely in the code you didn't show here. Also read this: [ask]

Comment: `char* buffer = (char*) calloc(strlen(input)*sizeof(char),0);` -- here, you allocate exactly, um, zero bytes. `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition and you'll need 1 extra byte to store the terminating `'\0'`. And the cast isn't needed in C, so `char* buffer = calloc(1, strlen(input) + 1);`.

Comment: Also, please don't use `strncat` to append single chars. Assign directly: `buffer[i++] = whatever` and terminate with a null when you're done: `buffer[i] = '\0';`

Comment: It's probably not your stack that is broken, but how you read the input. Perhaps you could just print the string instead of pushing it onto the stack and then debug your input parsing.

Comment: I tried to replace my line by `char* buffer = calloc(1, strlen(input) + 1);` but it doesn't change anything (at least for my problem).

Comment: Also, I added `printf`'s right before my push and the strings are correctly displayed

Comment: Please add a (minimal) `main`function that reproduces your problem with a call (or several calls?) to `str_to_stk` as necessary.

Comment: Using a macro like that is diabolical.  It may not work properly for array types like character strings; it doesn't allocate enough space for strings, nor use copy operations like `strcpy()` that are needed for strings.  It probably works for numeric types.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll add the `main` for future references.

Comment: I would advise to indent your code better. It would be more readable if at least `}` would be on separate lines. Inside macros I indent my code just like in normal C, just every line ends with `\`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without making any attempt to find all the errors in this code, there is a clear problem here where you push a token onto the stack:

```
  stk_str_push(output, buffer);
  input = input+i;
  free(buffer);
```

You've accumulated the token into the dynamically allocated `buffer`, and you push the pointer to the allocated storage onto the stack. But then you call `free` on that pointer, which terminates the lifetime of the dynamic allocation. That means that the pointer you've just pushed onto the stack can no longer be dereferenced, since it now points at a deleted object. Or, more accurately, it points into limbo. This is generally referred to as a "dangling pointer".

You must not `free()` an allocation until you no longer need the data it contains (which might be after you pop it from the stack, if you no longer need the popped value).

Also, later on in the same function, you demonstrate the other common way to create a dangling pointer:

```
  char buffer[2]; buffer[0] = input[0]; buffer[1] = '\0';
  stk_str_push(output, buffer);
```

Here, `buffer` is an automatic allocation, not a dynamic allocation. Automatic allocations live only until you leave the block containing the declaration, which ends shortly after you push the pointer onto the stack. By the time you get around to using that pointer, the `buffer` array will have long since disappeared, again making the pointer on the stack useless.

Comment: That was the answer. Thank you very much. I'm still new in C so I'm still not sure when I need to free. In this case, I guess I thought that since the stack now handles the memory, I do not need `buffer` and freed it. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @fulmen: The "stack" you're using only manages the things you're pushing onto the stack. In this case, your stack consists of *pointers*. Pointers are real objects in C; they are not the same as the thing they point to.